# Where are the savegames stored for Mario on the DS Lite

Tags: nintendo-ds

I was a few worlds into Mario for the DS Lite when we moved and I somehow lost the cartridge.

I've been thinking of buying another copy of the game to finish it, but I don't know if my save games are in the system or in the cartridge itself.

Where are they stored?

And if they were on the cartridge, are there convenient cheats to skip over the worlds that I played?

Comment: It's Mario!  It'll be fun to re-play.  ;)

Answer (score 11):

The Nintendo DS stores its save game data on the cartridges themselves. The limited built-in memory on the device itself is reserved for storing information like the profile name, Wi-Fi settings, etc.